# Custom function IPAddress Lookup

Tags: excel, vba

I am a Network Admin. Often I face this task to identify to which Range an IP Address belongs.

Since Excel doesn't inherently handle IP Addresses, I looked up a few  things on this site to try to develop a custom function.

IP Address Table  with Description
[image]

Data
[image]

In the adjacent column to IP Address, I need to run through each IP Address and if the IP is in a particular range, copy the corresponding description.

It should look like this:
[image]

How do I make the code generic, so the user can select the IP Address Range and the lookup Range, much like the VLookup formula?

Full code:

Courtesy of Steve Kline, the code to convert IP Address to Decimal number.

```vb
Function ip2dec(ip)
    ip0 = Split(ip, ".")(0)
    ip1 = Split(ip, ".")(1)
    ip2 = Split(ip, ".")(2)
    ip3 = Split(ip, ".")(3)
    
    dec = 0
    dec = ip0 * 256
    dec = dec + ip1
    dec = dec * 256
    dec = dec + ip2
    dec = dec * 256
    dec = dec + ip3
        
    ip2dec = dec
    
End Function
```

Using that I used a simple IF to check if an IP Address is within a given Range.

```vb
Function IP_in_Range(StartIP, EndIP, TestIP)
    If (ip2dec(TestIP) >= ip2dec(StartIP) And ip2dec(TestIP) <= ip2dec(EndIP)) Then
        IP_in_Range = True
    Else
        IP_in_Range = False
    End If
    
End Function
```

I used the above Ip_in_Range function to loop through the IP Address Range Table to find a match and copy the description text.

```vb
Function MatchIP(TestIP)

    Dim TotalRows As Integer
    Dim StartIP, EndIP, TextValue As String
        
    Dim r As Integer
    
    MatchIP = "Not in defined Range"
    
    TotalRows = Range("IPTable").Rows.Count
          
    For r = 2 To TotalRows
        Sheets("IPTable").Activate
        Sheets("IPTable").Range("IPTable").Select
        
        StartIP = Range("IPTable").Cells(r, 1).Value
        EndIP = Range("IPTable").Cells(r, 2).Value
        TextValue = Range("IPTable").Cells(r, 3).Value
        
        If (IP_in_Range(StartIP, EndIP, TestIP)) Then
            MatchIP = TextValue
        End If
    Next r
                
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the look-up data in Table2, ipaddr in cell A2 and this formula in cell B2 `=IpToDescr(A2,Table2)`.

```vb
Function IpToDescr(IP As Range, rng As Range) As String

    Dim sIP As String
    Dim ar: ar = rng.Value
    sIP = DecToHex(IP.Value)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
       If sIP >= DecToHex(ar(i, 1)) And _
          sIP <= DecToHex(ar(i, 2)) Then
          IpToDescr = ar(i, 3)
          Exit Function
       End If
    Next
    IpToDescr = ""
    
End Function

Function DecToHex(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim a, i As Long
    a = Split(s, ".")
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
       DecToHex = DecToHex & Right("0" & Hex(a(i)), 2)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks CDP1802. For converting the IP Addr from Dotted notation to Decimal, I should have used FOR loop. More elegant. As mentioned I am a complete novice in programming. Thank You once again.